# Why am I getting 'Error Unknown command "ext"' when the quasar-cli documentation says that is available?

Tags: quasar-framework

Currently I am using quasar-cli v2.0.0. I am trying to following the instructions [provided here](https://quasar.dev/start/quasar-cli).

```
npm i -g @quasar/cli
npm init quasar
```

Then I go into the folder and run per [the example](https://quasar.dev/app-extensions/introduction)...

```
quasar ext add @quasar/testing-unit-vitest
```

but when I run this I get...

> Error Unknown command "ext"

How do I install extensions in the latest version of quasar?

Comment: I'm facing with same error... did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue.
Try `quasar upgrade` then terminal show

```
@quasar/extras: Missing! → 1.15.11
@quasar/app-vite: Missing! → 1.2.1
```

so, let run `quasar upgrade -i` to install them

That all,